# Force Java timezone as GMT/UTC

Tags: java, timezone, utc, gmt

I need to force any time related operations to GMT/UTC, regardless the timezone set on the machine. Any convenient way to so in code?

To clarify, I'm using the DB server time for all operations, but it comes out formatted according to local timezone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The OP answered this question to change the default timezone for a single instance of a running JVM, set the `user.timezone` system property:

```
java -Duser.timezone=GMT ... <main-class>
```

If you need to set specific time zones when retrieving Date/Time/Timestamp objects from a database `ResultSet`, use the second form of the `getXXX` methods that takes a `Calendar` object:

```
Calendar tzCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
ResultSet rs = ...;
while (rs.next()) {
    Date dateValue = rs.getDate("DateColumn", tzCal);
    // Other fields and calculations
}
```

Or, setting the date in a PreparedStatement:

```
Calendar tzCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
PreparedStatement ps = conn.createPreparedStatement("update ...");
ps.setDate("DateColumn", dateValue, tzCal);
// Other assignments
ps.executeUpdate();
```

These will ensure that the value stored in the database is consistent when the database column does not keep timezone information.

The `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` classes store the actual time (milliseconds) in UTC. To format these on output to another timezone, use `SimpleDateFormat`. You can also associate a timezone with the value using a Calendar object:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("<local-time-zone>");
//...
Date dateValue = rs.getDate("DateColumn");
Calendar calValue = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
calValue.setTime(dateValue);
```

**Usefull Reference**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/troubleshoot/time-zone-settings-jre.htm#JSTGD377

https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/setting-the-timezone-for-the-java-environment-841187402.html

Comment: One thing to note about setting the timezone for the entire JVM is that it affects everything, including such things as logging. Just something to keep in mind if that's the desired effect.

Comment: Yep, that fine.

Just one point to mention, that I actually set the user.timezone directly in code, rather then via the -D parameter.

Comment: @SyBer: That works but you must ensure that you set this before any method calls the TimeZone.getDefault() method. If not you will have some confusion since the default is cached after the first execution. This also means it could be a problem if you do this inside an API/library (hidden from plain view) - be sure to document heavily what you are doing.

Answer (score 26):

Also if you can set JVM timezone this way

```
System.setProperty("user.timezone", "EST");
```

or `-Duser.timezone=GMT` in the JVM args.

Comment: `System.setProperty("user.timezone" ...)` doesn't work.

Comment: System.setProperty("user.timezone", "EST");
this is working fine. Thank you

Comment: @wilmol & @pravin-kottavar you are both correct – because it depends. As @syber correctly pointed out, this *only* works if `TimeZone.getDefault()` has never been called before. After that, the system property will no longer have an effect on how `java.util.Date` and other legacy Date classes interpret the current timezone. From then on, only changing it via `TimeZone.setDefault()` will work. If that is a good idea, that's another discussion. We should all just start consequently using the proper `java.time.*` stuff – respecting the environment, instead of trying to change it as a last resort.

Answer (score 21):

You could change the timezone using [TimeZone.setDefault()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault%28java.util.TimeZone%29):

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
```

Comment: No offence, but modifying temporarily a global static state sounds like a very bad idea...

Comment: You could, but you shouldn't.

This is extraordinarily bad advice. The entire JVM has its timezone changed.

Comment: Sometimes it is exactly what you want to achieve. Eg. I have seen Java-based microservices running always with UTC to avoid time zone problems. In these systems the database backend runs with UTC as well, so it is natural to "force" the JVM to UTC as well.
What is important: you have to know what you are doing and what are the consequences...

Comment: absolutely not. If you want your entire system in UTC (a very good idea), set the system timezone to UTC and leave the Java timezone alone.

Comment: Except if you have multiple JVMs with different requirements. We can argue forever but every case is unique: sometimes you need to set the entire system's timezone, sometimes you set only one JVM's. Let's be happy that today's systems are so flexible that we can do both 

Answer (score 13):

I had to set the JVM timezone for Windows 2003 Server because it always returned GMT for new Date();

`-Duser.timezone=America/Los_Angeles`

Or your appropriate time zone. Finding a list of time zones proved to be a bit challenging also...

Here are two list;

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-timezone.html

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzatz%2F51%2Fadmin%2Freftz.htm

Answer (score 12):

## tl;dr

```
String sql = "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
…
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( 1 , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Avoid depending on host OS or JVM for default time zone

I recommend you write all your code to explicitly state the desired/expected time zone. You need not depend on the JVM’s current default time zone. And be aware that the JVM’s current default time zone can change *at any moment* during runtime, with any code in any thread of any app calling `TimeZone.setDefault`. Such a call affects all apps within that JVM immediately.

## *java.time*

Some of the other Answers were correct, but are now outmoded. The terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java were flawed, written by people who did not understand the complexities and subtleties of date-time handling.

The legacy date-time classes have been supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

To represent a time zone, use [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html). To represent an offset-from-UTC, use [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html). An offset is merely a number of hour-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the prime meridian. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

> I need to force any time related operations to GMT/UTC

For an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds, use  the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

### `Instant`

To capture the current moment in UTC, use an `Instant`. This class represent a moment in UTC, always in UTC by definition.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

To see that same moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, adjust into a time zone. Same moment, same point on the timeline,  different wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

### Database

You mention a database.

To retrieve a moment from the database, your column should be of a data type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Retrieve an object rather than a string. In JDBC 4.2 and later, we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database. The `OffsetDateTime` is required by JDBC, while `Instant` & `ZonedDateTime` are optional.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

In most databases and drivers, I would guess  that you will get the moment as seen in UTC. But if not, you can adjust in either of two ways:

- Extract a `Instant`:  `odt.toInstant()`
- Adjust from the given offset to an offset of zero: OffsetDateTime odtUtc = odt.withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;`.

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 8):

for me, just quick SimpleDateFormat,

```
  private static final SimpleDateFormat GMT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  private static final SimpleDateFormat SYD = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  static {
      GMT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    SYD.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));
  }
```

then format the date with different timezone.

Answer (score 8):

Use system property:

```
-Duser.timezone=UTC
```

Comment: Why should one use that? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 6):

I would retrieve the time from the DB in a raw form (long timestamp or java's Date), and then use SimpleDateFormat to format it, or Calendar to manipulate it. In both cases you should set the timezone of the objects before using it.

See `SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(..)` and `Calendar.setTimeZone(..)` for details

Answer (score 1):

create a pair of client / server, so that after the execution, client server sends the correct time and date. Then, the client asks the server pm GMT and the server sends back the answer right.

Answer (score 1):

Execute this line in MySQL to reset your timezone:

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+00:00';
```

Comment: How is this a solution to the timezone in Java?

Comment: i think he need a deep rest... lol :D

Answer (score 1):

Hope below code will help you.

```
    DateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_DATE_TIME_PATTERN);
    formatDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); 
    formatDate.parse(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I know this is an ancient thread but all I can say is do not call TimeZone.setDefault() in any user-level code. This always sets the Timezone for the whole JVM and is nearly *always* a very bad idea. Learn to use the joda.time library or the new DateTime class in Java 8 which is very similar to the joda.time library.

Comment: I use it for tests. I never know what timezone my teammates have on their computers or what's going to be set on the CI.

Answer (score -6):

If you would like to get GMT time only with intiger:
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentYear ='2010'
    var currentMonth = 10;
    var currentDay ='30'
    var currentHours ='20'
    var currentMinutes ='20'
    var currentSeconds ='00'
    var currentMilliseconds ='00'

```
currentTime.setFullYear(currentYear);
currentTime.setMonth((currentMonth-1)); //0is January
currentTime.setDate(currentDay);  
currentTime.setHours(currentHours);
currentTime.setMinutes(currentMinutes);
currentTime.setSeconds(currentSeconds);
currentTime.setMilliseconds(currentMilliseconds);

var currentTimezone = currentTime.getTimezoneOffset();
currentTimezone = (currentTimezone/60) * -1;
var gmt ="";
if (currentTimezone !== 0) {
  gmt += currentTimezone > 0 ? ' +' : ' ';
  gmt += currentTimezone;
}
alert(gmt)
```

Comment: that looks like JavaScript (!= Java) to me.