# Will my database timestamp fields get automatically converted to GUI user's timezone

Tags: java, user-interface, timezone

I have a bunch of timestamp fields in my java model bean which is sent the view. If a user in another country or timezone tries to view these fields, will they be shown in the user's timezone. If not, could you provide a code snippet to do this conversion to the users timezone.

[Update] Adeels reply below will work, and this following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627992/force-java-timezone-as-gmt-utc) shows how to set it when getting the bean from database itself.

Comment: Try to solve your problem, *then* post a question containing the portion/s of code you're stuck with

Comment: Do you mean in a webapp?

Comment: @Michael ok, I posted it because did not know how to test code even if I wrote it. @Adeel, yes in a web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the user's time zone, and use [`Calendar.setTimeZone()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) to set the time zone and retrieve the `Timestamp` according to the user's time zone. You can instantiate `Calendar` using that `TimeZone`, i.e.

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(userTimeZone);
```

Or you can set it afterwards like,

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(userTimeZone);
```

Comment: If I set Calendar.setTimeZone() will the default timezone of my whole application be changed? Meaning, will it affect only that session or everyone using the app

Comment: Get calendar instance like this, `Calender.getInstance(TimeZone...)`. Then only that instance will be having that timezone. Further, see my addendum to the post.

Comment: This will work but only thing is I need to manually convert each field in my java bean using this new cal/simpledateformat. I have added a link to my post, which seems to be the right way to do it. They are picking up the values with the timezone format from database this way I dont need to set all fields.

Comment: @Abe: I didn't say that you should do it for every field. You presumed it yourself ;). Yes, indeed the link provided is having several ways to do it. You can see that in that thread the poster is also using this technique, as I suggested. But he went further and provided the convenient way of doing it. May be because OP specifically asked for it. I'm glad you find it. Happy coding.