# JMeter - How to measure exact response time if distance between client and server is too far

Tags: time, jmeter, response

I'm beginner in JMeter and I have a issues with it: when I run jmeter on Vietnam and test a server on US and user "View Results in Table" to view result. In this report, I want to know how to calculate "Sample Time"? It's time the server response or time which client received response? and how to effect if distance between client and server is too far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sampler Time will be the time of Vietnam.

But you can configure your JMeter instance to use the US Timezone through System property:

> -Duser.timezone=

See:

- [Force Java timezone as GMT/UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627992/force-java-timezone-as-gmt-utc)

Regarding Response Time, it will include latency due to you being far from US but it will reflect what Vietnam users will face. 
So if your requirement is to measure US feeling then you will need to load test from a US server, if your requirement is to measure Vietnamese feeling on a US hosted application then it's ok.

Comment: I mean sample time (ms), not start time. I want to know the sample time i got in Vietname is correct or incorrect? Is it depend bandwidth of network between Vietnam and US?

Comment: Yes absolutely, that's the second part of my answer regarding Response Time.